# Why can my property name not be of type string?

Tags: typescript, webstorm, typechecking

I am trying to write some code that does something to a set of string property names from an arbitrary interface/class (supplied as a generic parameter).

My first attempt looked like this:

```js
function doSomething<T extends object>(props: (keyof T)[]) {
    for (let prop of props) {
        const x: string = prop;
    }
}
```

This causes a compiler error in the line starting with `const`:

> TS2322: Type 'string | number | symbol' is not assignable to type 'string'.
>   Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'string'.

Now, the first line seems clear - `keyof T` may be a string, but may also be a number, or a symbol.

The second line is, however, unexpected to me - why would the compiler assume that `prop` is a `number` and nothing else? Or is it just an example for a possible, conflicting case?

In any case, I thought I could simply restrict my loop body to treat only those property names that are strings:

```js
function doSomething<T extends object>(props: (keyof T)[]) {
    for (let prop of props) {
        if (typeof prop === 'string') {
            const x: string = prop;
        }
    }
}
```

But now, my typechecking condition `typeof prop === 'string'` is highlighted, with a message saying:

> Invalid 'typeof' check: 'prop' cannot have type 'string'

Why wouldn't `prop` ever be a string? When I call my function with a sample class, I sure can pass an array of strings (as long as those strings match property names of the sample class, obviously).

Or are those strings somehow implicitly cast to `symbol`? As a matter of fact, if I change the typecheck condition to `typeof prop === 'symbol'`, there is no warning anymore that this would never match. But then, in the first error message, `keyof T` was explicitly said to be either string or number or symbol, so in what case *would* it be a string at all?

---

My code is now in a state to be run in a Jest unit test, and - surprise, surprise - turns out `prop` actually *is* a string. The suggestion that it cannot have type string is effectively wrong. (Unfortunately, I cannot turn it off because WebStorm does not give away what part in the toolchain generated the message.)

This *might* be related to [bug WEB-49787](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-49787).

Answer (score 0):

> The second line is, however, unexpected to me - why would the compiler assume that prop is a number and nothing else?

It's not assuming that, it's just walking through all the possibilities of the union. Typescript considers the case where it's a `string` and sees no problem. Then it considers the case where it's a `number`, and that one results in an error, so it shows that. `symbol` would also cause an error, but for brevity, typescript just shows the first problem it finds.

Put another way: line 2 is explaining how typescript deduced the error on line 1

> But now, my typechecking condition typeof prop === 'string' is highlighted, with a message saying:
>
> > Invalid 'typeof' check: 'prop' cannot have type 'string'
>
> Why wouldn't prop ever be a string?

That's not a typescript error. For example, you won't see it in [this typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAEzgZTgWwKZQBYxgDmAPACqLYAeU2YyAzonAEYBW20AfABQAOAJzh8GALkQ8A1tgCecYIjIBKANoBdJYgDeAWABQiQ4mBwBEgDa5Eg4cwU2Rm3QaOuYCnlBl9s860L5EAF4QxAByBigBQiIwp31XRKMIBEjEKnFI6OJg-2EAbgSkxABfIsMyvRKgA). It's probably a lint error. A google search led me to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50861302/why-is-typeof-v-string-considered-invalid-by-eslint) which may be related.

Comment: Aha, the initial mention of `number` is thus indeed just an example, I see. As for the typecheck issue, I am using WebStorm and I often find it hard to determine where (what tool/part in the build process) a given message comes from. With that said, I had already come across the linked question, but it refers to a completely different issue - note that the other message just recommends using `angular.isString` over `typeof ... === 'string'`, while the message I am getting claims the condition will *never* be met.